# how to calculate a profit/loss on multiple currency trading

Tags: foreign-exchange

I would like to understand if there is a rationale behind a multiple currency trade on whether one makes a profit or loss. Let me give an example:

Say I have `250000 HKD(Hong Kong dollar)` and I `sell the HKD to buy USD` at this rate:

```
USD.HKD rate=7.789
```

I get **32096 USD**.

Great now I have **32096 USD** on my hands and say I want to trade my `USD to EUR` at:

```
EUR.USD rate = 1.1149
```

Is there a way to calculate my profit/loss in this multiple currency trade i.e. `HKD -> USD -> EUR` ??

Comment: Just compare back to your base currency at any point in time?

Comment: that makes sense, but say my base currency is EUR and I start with HKD. How can I say I made a profit in EUR if at any point in time I have never had EUR in the first place ?

Comment: Most people start with their base currency, but if not you just need to know the value of your starting position in your base currency, so you could refer to a historic forex value for the point in time when you made your first trade.

Comment: ok so I started with `HKD` and sold to buy `USD`, now I have `USD` and I want `EUR` as my final trade. So in order to calculate my profit/loss I should refer to the `EUR` quotation at the point in time when I sold `HKD` for `USD` ? That doesn't make sense to me. If I start with 0 USD and EUR and 250000 HKD then I need to necessarily go back to HKD at some point to calculate my profit/loss right ?

Comment: You would start with the HKD:EUR rate at the time you traded away from HKD if you want to calculate P/L in terms of EUR, if you want to calculate P/L in terms of HKD then you just need to look at current HKD:EUR rate. It's most straightforward to calculate P/L using the currency you started with.

Answer (score 1):

The USD/HKD is 7.79224, the EUR/USD is 1.11503, and the EUR/HKD is 8.68876.

Well, the reciprocal of 1.11503 is 0.8968369 . One USD buys 0.8968369 EUR.

So 0.8968369 EUR relates to 7.79224 HKD as 1 EUR relates to x. That's 7.79224 / 0.8968369 for 8.68858 as the calculated EUR/HKD.

Well, the EUR/HKD is quoted at 8.68876 but the trading basis is 8.68858. That's some percentage rise in the EUR and some percentage loss in HKD.

Comment: Well, I assumed that the trader just didn't have access to an exchange of HKD for EUR. So then I calculated a EUR/HKD from the other two trades so that profit/loss in HKD could be easily accounted.